# I can't install any new software, i keep getting this message

Tags: apt, software-installation

> ```
> 'Ubuntu 18.04 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180426)' in the drive
>    '/media/cdrom/' and press [Enter]
> ```

When I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, nothing happens. I tried updating and upgrading my packages so that’s not the issue.

I’m new at Ubuntu so I don’t know what else to do.

Comment: @DavidFoerster why you like to scroll this message? It is unreadable and ugly that way ("`>`").

Comment: @DavidFoerster You are absolutely right about formatting, but on my Firefox ESR it is scrollable (see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkZpy.png)).

Comment: @N0rbert Not just ESR, Quantum adds scrollbars as well.

Comment: @N0rbert: My mistake. I forgot the user style sheet that forces the style `white-space: pre-wrap` onto all `<pre>` nodes (precisely because I don't like to scroll horizontally).

Comment: @PerlDuck SeaMonkey and Chromium too. Of course I mistaken - instead of `>` I mean four spaces. Opened [thread on Meta](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/18054/66509).

Comment: @DavidFoerster do not forget to visit [discussion on Meta](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/18054/66509).

Answer (score 13):

You should:

1. open *Software & Updates* (or `software-properties-gtk` from terminal)
2. then in the area named *Installable from CD-ROM/DVD* uncheck the *Cdrom with Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver)*.

   [image: Software & Updates - disable CDROM]
3. make sure that you do not have checked *Cdrom with Ubuntu 18.04 'Bionic Beaver'* on *Other Software* tab:

   [image: Software & Updates - other software]
4. to keep your system secure on *Updates* tab enable security updates (*bionic-security*, *bionic-updates*, *bionic-backports*):

   [image: Software & Updates - updates]

Comment: what does the cdrom with ubuntu 'bionic serve ' do?

Comment: Usually it was a CD/DVD medium from where the system were installed first time.