# When I try to start settings or Rhythmbox, Ubuntu forces me to log in again

Tags: settings

I am new to Ubuntu and recently installed it. It took me a while to make Ubuntu actually boot. When I finally managed to boot into Ubuntu I tried clicking on settings, and this showed a black screen and forced me to log in again.

The same thing happens when I try running `Rhythmbox`. I've tried googling this problem, but none of the solutions I've found have worked so far.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.2.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally solved my problem! basically what i've done is follow 3 articles:

1. https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=122257
2. [I can't install any new software, i keep getting this message](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056309/i-cant-install-any-new-software-i-keep-getting-this-message)
3. https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux